# Auto unmount USB drive on logout, scary?

Tags: usb, unmount

My machine has 2 users. Whichever user logs on first "owns" the backup drive attached by USB more or less permanently. This means that if user logs out/switch user, the second user cannot access the USB drive after login and neither can the deja-dup backup program.

## Is there any way to force the USB drive to unmount on user logout?